What is the full form of the word " Special Ops" ? I am asking this question in military context
I have googled this question. But I just wanted to get a human answer to it. What is the full form of the word "Special Ops" ?
I looked this in dictionary. But the dictionary did not explicitly say that " special ops " means " special operations" . That is why I am asking this here. Pls answer.
